# How to run robotframework file, from another directory using batch file?

Tags: batch-file, cmd, command-line, command-line-interface, robotframework

Example path:

> 1. Folder1
>
>    - test.robot
> 2. folder2
>
>    - execute.bat

my bat file:

> 1. CALL C:
> 2. CALL cd %~dp0
> 3. CALL robot folder1\test.robot

but failed: File or directory to execute does not exist
Please advise

Comment: One thing is for sure, none of your command lines should use the command `CALL`, (unless `robot` is really `robot.bat` or `robot.cmd`, if so `CALL` on the last line can remain). Now change line 1 to `CD /D "%~dp0"`, then remove your existing line 2.

Answer (score 0):

From the location: %~dp0 , provide the path to robot file. For example like this -
..\folder1\test.robot

To confirm if the path is correct, try to CD to that path -

```
cd ..\folder1\
```

Then run the robot command like this -

```
CALL robot ..\folder1\test.robot
```

Please note I dont know the complete path from dp0 folder so I have assumed it